# UPDATE using CTE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, cte

I am trying to update the single table with 4 columns `(run_id, fqcn, diff_value, cleared_run_id)`  with the following snippet:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT diff.fqcn, diff.run_id, diff.cleared_run_id, diff.diff_value, SUM(diff.diff_value) OVER (PARTITION BY diff.fqcn ORDER BY diff.fqcn, diff.run_id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS current_value
    FROM sonar_resource_diff diff
    GROUP BY diff.fqcn, diff.run_id, diff.diff_value, diff.cleared_run_id
)

UPDATE sr SET sr.cleared_run_id = sr.run_id FROM sonar_resource_diff sr
INNER JOIN cte ON (cte.fqcn = sr.fqcn AND cte.run_id = sr.run_id)
WHERE cte.current_value = 0
```

The problem is that it only updates rows where running total is 0, while I need to update that row AND rows where `run_id` < row where running total value is 0 so it will look like this in the end:

[image]

This is what it looks like before the update as the `cleared_run_id` is the only column that needs to be updated:

[image]

How would I need to modify the statement to achieve that?

Comment: I don't quite follow from the screen shot which rows *should* be updated, where new cleared_run_id values should come from, or even whether the screen shot is before the update, after the update, or what you want as the desired result. Instead of the query that doesn't work and a screen shot, can you please provide sample data before the update, and how you want the data to look like after the update? [PLEASE READ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for replying. The screenshot is done after the update, `cleared_run_id` are all NULL at the beginning, to show what I am trying to achieve. `cleared_run_id` s should be updated with `run_id` values where running total, `current_value` is 0, in a manner shown above.

Comment: Please show before and after, not just after. And it is easier if you provide the data as insert statements, not screen shots, so we can work with it on our own systems instead of transcribing from tiny columns in a screen shot.

Comment: @Victor please provide sample table data (with INSERT statements) as Aaron commented, so others can answer. It's also not clear if the table has a `current_value` column or not.

Comment: @ypercube Thanks for the feedback, `current_value` is a calculated field as shown in CTE statement

Comment: You can use [dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/) to load sample data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems - although it's not all clear - that you want a running total per `fqcn`, so the `GROUP BY` you have doesn't make sense.

For the update, it appears that we are looking at a gaps-and-islands problem. Each "island" or group is identified / ends by a row that has `current_value = 0`. There are a few ways to solve gaps-and-islands problems, you can look at the questions of the site that have been tagged with [gaps-and-islands](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands).

Something like this might do what you are after. I use a second CTE to separate the rows into groups:

```
 ;
WITH 
  cte AS
  ( SELECT fqcn, run_id, cleared_run_id, diff_value, 
           current_value = SUM(diff_value) OVER 
               ( PARTITION BY fqcn
                 ORDER BY run_id 
                 ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING )
    FROM sonar_resource_diff
  ),
  cte2 AS
  ( SELECT *, 
           grp = COUNT(CASE WHEN current_value = 0 THEN 1 END) OVER
               ( PARTITION BY fqcn
                 ORDER BY run_id 
                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
    FROM cte
  )
UPDATE sr 
SET sr.cleared_run_id = mark.run_id 
FROM cte2 AS sr
     JOIN cte2 AS mark
     ON  mark.fqcn = sr.fqcn 
     AND mark.grp = sr.grp
     AND mark.current_value = 0
 ;
```

Comment: Not sure how to use `dbfiddle` but the snippet seems to give me exactly what I need.